# redis sentinel high availability haproxy

Tags: docker, redis, kubernetes, haproxy, sentinel

I am checking *Redis* high availability solution via configuration of master and slave *Redis Kubernetes* pods and sentinel on top of it. For failover of external client connections, I installed *haproxy* pod. I encountered with some issue while started testing the configuration:

1. *Redis* is closing forwarding connections from HAPROXY - client reporting error

> Error: Server closed the connection.

BTW: if *Redis* is configured with an empty password, the connection is passing OK.

I appreciate any idea and advice. My HA proxy cfg file has the following entries:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 500

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout         server 50000ms

frontend rotatingproxies
    bind *:3000
    default_backend rotateproxy
    option http_proxy
    option http-use-proxy-header

backend rotateproxy
    option http_proxy 
    server proxyserver user:pass@domain.com:9999
    server proxyserver user:pass@domain.com:9999
    balance roundrobin
```

Comment: Some update Actually im using tcp mode in my configuration

Comment: defaults REDIS
 mode tcp
 timeout connect  4s
 timeout server  30s
 timeout client  30s
 
frontend ft_redis
 bind 10.0.0.1:6379 name redis
 default_backend bk_redis
 
backend bk_redis
 option tcp-check
 tcp-check send PINGrn
 tcp-check expect string +PONG
 tcp-check send info replicationrn
 tcp-check expect string role:master
 tcp-check send QUITrn
 tcp-check expect string +OK
 server R1 10.0.0.11:6379 check inter 1s
 server R2 10.0.0.12:6379 check inter 1s

Answer (score 1):

Increase 
**timeout client** 
and **timeout server** to values at least two times more than **tcp-keepalive** in **redis.conf** file (default 300 s,my recommendation 60s)

For e.g:
if `tcp-keepalive 60`
than

```
timeout server 120s
timeout client 120s
```